# Laravel: full-calendar displayEventTime doesn't display the time correctly (12a)

Tags: php, laravel, fullcalendar, laravel-8, fullcalendar-3

I'm trying to create a full calendar with laravel for an application I'm working on. I have created some cards that have the names of some providers and I want to display the time when the event starts on the card at the beginning.

I understand that fullCalendar has a calendar parameter called `displayEventTime`. However, when I set it to true I only get `12a` in all of my cards, no matter when the actual event takes place. I Googled and I found that this is because the time is default at `00:00`. So, I'm guessing that either some time format is wrong or that the time start/end doesn't pass to the event from the controller.

How can I pull for each event it's start/end time and display it on the cards?

**View**:

```php
var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            events: SITEURL + "/availabilityHours?providerTypeID={{$providerTypeID}}",
            editable: false,
            //timeFormat: 'H(:mm)',
            displayEventTime: true,
            selectable: true,
            selectHelper: true,
            eventRender: function (event, element, view) {
                event.allDay = false;
            },
            select: function (start, end, allDay) {
                window.location.href = SITEURL + "/availabilityHours/create?eventDate=" + start.unix();
            },
             
            eventDrop: function (event, delta) {
                        console.log('dragged and dropped')
                    },
            eventClick: function (event) {
                window.location.href = SITEURL + "/availabilityHours/" + event.id + "/edit";
            }
        });
    });
```

**Controller**:

```php
public function index(AvailabilityHourDataTable $availabilityHourDataTable, Request $request)
    {
        //return $availabilityHourDataTable->render('availability_hours.index');
        
        if(request()->ajax()) 
        {
 
            $start = (!empty($_GET["start"])) ? ($_GET["start"]) : ('');
            $end = (!empty($_GET["end"])) ? ($_GET["end"]) : ('');
            $providerTypeID = (!empty($_GET["providerTypeID"])) ? ($_GET["providerTypeID"]) : ('0');
        
            $providers = $providerTypeID == 0 ?
                $this->eProviderRepository->all()->pluck('id') : 
                $this->eProviderRepository->where('e_provider_type_id', $providerTypeID)->pluck('id');
            
            $data = $this->availabilityHourRepository
                    ->getModel()
                    ->whereDate('day', '>=', $start)
                    ->whereDate('day', '<=', $end)
                    ->whereIn('e_provider_id', $providers)
                    ->get();
            $responceData = [];

            
            foreach($data as $entry){
                $date = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $entry->day, 'UTC')->setTimezone('Europe/Athens');
                $eProvider = $this->eProviderRepository->findWithoutFail($entry->e_provider_id);
                
                $newEntry = [
                    'id' => $entry->id,
                    'title' => $eProvider->name,
                    'date' => $date,
                    'color' => $eProvider->color,
                ];
                $responceData[] = $newEntry;
            }
            
            return Response::json($responceData);
        }
        
        $providerTypes = $this->eProviderTypeRepository->all()->pluck('name', 'id');
        $providerTypes['0'] = 'All';
        $providerTypeID = isset($request->providerTypeID) ? $request->providerTypeID : 0;
        
        return view('availability_hours.index2', compact('providerTypeID', 'providerTypes'));
    }
```

**Model:**

```php
public static $rules = [
        'day' => 'required',
        'start_at' => 'required|date_format:H\:i',
        'end_at' => 'required|date_format:H\:i|after:start_at',
        'data' => 'max:255',
        'e_provider_id' => 'required|exists:e_providers,id'
    ];
    public $translatable = [
        'data',
    ];
    public $timestamps = false;
    public $table = 'availability_hours';
    public $fillable = [
        'day',
        'start_at',
        'end_at',
        'data',
        'e_provider_id'
    ];
```

The calendar in question:

[image]

**

**EDIT:** I followed @ADyson's solution and i parsed the time correctly. However now, I don't get the end time.
Here are the changes I did to Controller/View.

**Controller**

```php
foreach($data as $entry){
                $date = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i', $entry->day->toDateString().' '.$entry->start_at, 'UTC');
                $endDate = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i', $entry->day->toDateString().' '.$entry->end_at, 'UTC');
                $eProvider = $this->eProviderRepository->findWithoutFail($entry->e_provider_id);
                
                $newEntry = [
                    'id' => $entry->id,
                    'title' => $eProvider->name,
                    'date' => $date,
                    'endDate' => $endDate,
                    'color' => $eProvider->color,
                ];
                $responceData[] = $newEntry;                
            }
            
            return Response::json($responceData);
```

**View**

```php
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var SITEURL = "{{url('/')}}";
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });
 
        var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            events: SITEURL + "/availabilityHours?providerTypeID={{$providerTypeID}}",
            editable: false,
            displayEventTime: true,
            timeFormat: 'H:mm',
            displayEventEnd: true,
            selectable: true,
            selectHelper: true,
            select: function (start, end, allDay) {
                window.location.href = SITEURL + "/availabilityHours/create?eventDate=" + start.unix();
            },
            eventDrop: function (event, delta) {
                        console.log('dragged and dropped')
                    },
            eventClick: function (event) {
                window.location.href = SITEURL + "/availabilityHours/" + event.id + "/edit";
            }
        });
    });
    $('#providerType').change(function(ev) {
        console.log(ev.target.value)
        let optionValue = ev.target.value
        document.location.href="{!!route('availabilityHours.index')!!}" + "?providerTypeID=" + optionValue;
    });
    </script>
```

```
[enter image description here][2]
```

**

Comment: What is the content of `$entry` in your code, for each of those events? If there's no time specified in there, then you won't get a time in the calendar either.

Comment: I think this post my be help you: [Laravel fullcalendar with add, edit, delete and view event](https://devnote.in/laravel-fullcalendar-with-add-edit-delete-and-view-event/)

Comment: @ADyson sorry for the delayed answer but the contents in my $entry have only the date i think. I assume i need to pass the day together with the time,because in my model i have the day, start_at, end_at. That's why the calendar loads the dates but not the times. Do you have any direction for this?

Comment: @FefarRavi I found that article before as well, but it didn't help me so much. I didn't write this calendar (my colleague did) but i need to make some changes to it. I think that article would help more if I wrote it from scratch. Thanks though!

Comment: `i think`...don't think or assume or guess - test and verify instead, and let us know. `I assume i need to pass the day together with the time`...yes you do, just concatenate them together and ensure they make a valid date in the format required by fullCalendar 3 (which is actually anything that momentJS can parse. The most obvious and reliable format would be an ISO8601 compatible string, such as YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm). Carbon can potentially help you with formatting, if you prefer, rather than bare concatenation. might depend a bit how the data is stored in your database / model.

Comment: Okey, Basically i followed your instructions @ADyson and I managed to pass the time properly. Turns out I was parsing the wrong fields with Carbon. Thank you very much.
Now I want to make the end time appear as well but I don't know how to transfer it from the controller to the view. I tried to put "displayEventEnd: true" but it didn't change anything. Do you have any ideas?
P.S.> I'll edit my post to add the solution for the first part of the problem.

Comment: Change `'endDate' => $endDate` to `'end' => $endDate`. Your event object's property names must match the ones which fullCalendar expects - see the [documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/event-object) to know which property names it recognises. (Strictly, your `date` ought to be `start` as well but I think in that particular case in fullCalendar 3 it would actually accept `date` even though it's undocumented.)

Comment: @ADyson Well, you sir are an MVP. I've set it up like I wanted (mostly). Thank you for all the help through out! I'm new to SO, so how can I tag your answer as the most helpful?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If there's no time specified in the data you pass to fullCalendar, then you won't get a time in the calendar. In your case it seems to be `$entry` which is at fault and contains only a date (without a time).

Since your date and time are stored separately, you can just concatenate them together and ensure they make a valid date in the format required by fullCalendar 3 (which is actually anything that momentJS can parse. The most obvious and reliable format would be an ISO8601 compatible string, such as `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm`). Carbon can potentially help you with formatting, if you prefer, rather than bare concatenation. might depend a bit how the data is stored in your database / model.

Secondly, to make your end times show up, change `'endDate' => $endDate to 'end' => $endDate`. Your event object's property names must match the ones which fullCalendar expects - see the [documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/event-object) to know which property names it recognises. (Strictly, your `date` ought to be `start` as well but I think in that particular case in fullCalendar 3 it would actually accept date even though it's undocumented.)